# class attribute's value is emptied

Tags: php, laravel, class

I'm trying to set a value in my test class that will be used across the functions of the class.
So in my case I'm setting the $listId in function a and when I try to use it in function b the value is of it is reset

here's an example of the code:

```
class testing extends TestCase {

  private $listId;

  public function a(){
    $this->listId = "some value";
    
    print($this->listId); //some value
  }

  public function b(){
    
    print($this->listId); // <nothing is printed here>
    print(gettype($this->listId)); //null

  }
```

Anybody can tell if I'm doing something wrong.
This would work for me in any OO language so is this a php thing. and is there any alternative to use a variable that I've set in one function for other functions in the class.
I'm avoiding returning the value and passing it as a parameter from a to b (that would really mess up the structure of my code because there are a lot of functions there and they are already depending on each others)

I'm running the class using terminal command:
`phpunit path/to/class/testing`
so I'm not instantiating the class and calling the functions from an object

Comment: @NicklasKevinFrank
here is the code. 
I want to print the value of $listId in function b after setting it in function a

Comment: show where you call a and b function

Comment: I run it from terminal, 
it a test class for some api calls

Answer (score -1):

You assign a value to your property inside of your constructor, now you can assign that value to another method, BUT you need to create a new instance of your class to let the method actually assign that value.